# What is the conditional distribution of $X_3$ where $dX_t = adt + dW_t$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Suppose $X_t$ satisfies the stochastic differential equation $dX_t = adt + dW_t$ ($a$ is a constant). What is the conditional distribution of $X_3$ given the values $X_0=0$, $X_1=-1$, $X_4=2$, and $X_5=1$?

My intuition says the process should be Gaussian but the only solution I've seen to such a problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263122/what-is-the-conditional-distribution-of-bs-mid-bt-1-x-1-bt-2-x-2-for-0), which uses a joint normal distribution approach. What are some other ways to approach a solution?

Comment: What's wrong about using the approach presented in the linked question? Since $X_t = a t + W_t$ we know that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is Gaussian and also the mean/covariance can be calculated explicitly.

Comment: What is the conditional distribution of $W_3$ given the values $W_1=x$, $W_4=y$? What is the conditional distribution of $W_3$ given the values $W_0=0$, $W_1=-1-a$, $W_4=2-4a$, and $W_5=1-5a$? What is the conditional distribution of $W_3+3a$ given the same values?

Comment: @saz There is nothing wrong with that approach. I'm simply wondering if there are other ways to approach it, and what those other ways are.

Comment: @Did How were you able to isolate the values for the $W_4,W_5$ that are after $X_3$? Don't they depend on $W_3$?

Comment: You might be aware that the distribution of $W_3$ conditionally on $(W_s)_{s\leqslant1}$ and $(W_s)_{s\geqslant4}$ coincides with the distribution of $W_3$ conditionally on $(W_1,W_4)$. Are you not?